# ssh via public ip address

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ip, router

I have a VisionFive V1 risc v single board computer running Fedora. It is connected along with a raspberry pi to a router. The router has port 22 open and a public ip address. I can access the raspberry pi using ssh@public_ip_address but not the VisionFive. I can ssh into the VisionFive from the RaspPi in the subnet: but I want access via the public IP address to the VisionFive. There is no firewall with any filters on either machine. What are the diagnostic steps to identify the cause of the difference / problem. Why is one computer accessible via ssh and the public IP address and the other not?
[image: comparison of visionfive and rasppi]

Comment: Do not post pictures. Add the text to the question using codeblocks. Add the contents of the logs to the question as well.

Comment: How can you distinguish the two systems that use private IP addresses, both behind the *single* public IP address? Why would one system be selected and not the other? This is done on the router. And I guess only *you* can tell what was done on the router.

Comment: I'm guessing that your router is set to forward TCP port 22 to your Raspberry Pi (possibly by DMZ). You need to set a different TCP port in the router (e.g. 2222) to be redirected to your VisionFive TCP port 22. Then you can connect from outside using that port e.g. `ssh -p54022 root@public_ip_address`

Comment: These are the router settings [link](http://www.whatwasitagain.com/assets/o2spot/2022-04-11%20router%20settings%202.png).  If the pi computer is off, there is still no connection to the Fedora StarFive SBC via ssh over the public ip address. Both the pi and the Fedora StarFive have the same public ip address. Why should one work and not the other....  @gogoud Will test using -p54022 but cannot find any reference for that command..... any help welcome.

Comment: This question can only be solved on the router. As it is this is not a Unix/Linux question. And of course you can't put the same wan port settings for both systems on the router (its GUI interface should have forbidden such attempt). And no both Fedora StarFive and Pi have a different *private* IP address and don't have a public IP address: the ones obfuscated on the [link](http://www.whatwasitagain.com/assets/o2spot/2022-04-11%20router%20settings%202.png).

Comment: Thanks, but 
curl ifconfig.me 
for each computer shows the same public IP address and I can ssh into the pi over an o2 LTE/3G cellular router, from a completely different internet connection (vodaphone cable or o2 DSL). Any ideas what the WAN setting should be?

Comment: This question belongs to https://superuser.com/ not here. Because it's about the router which isn't offering a standard Unix/Linux interface (eg: a shell). And you appear to not understand what means private IP address. Have a look there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: As already stated, on router you must set *different* WAN ports for Pi and StarFive.

Comment: @gogoud Thanks. I have worked out what you mean and set the WAN entries different, and the LAN entries in both TCP and UDP to 22 and hey presto: I can log into the pi and into the StarFive using username@public_ip_address from outside the local subnet. Thanks very much for pointing me to this. (I was initially confused by the -p not being -p2222, and the omission of the statement WAN in "set to a different TCPP port"). I am really very grateful that you are so kind as to explain to a novice such elementary things. As for this not being a UNIX topic - well it is for me !